# Python list comprehension even string length or not

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I am trying to print "even" or not with list comprehension, but I get an error.

```
myNames = ['A','BB','CCC','DDDD']
myList3 = [ 'even' if x%2==0 else 'nope' for x in myNames]

Error: TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

What is the reason behind it?

Comment: How would a string be even? Are you trying to test the *length*?

Comment: Thank you!!! Feel like dumb right now. Yes wanted to test their length

Comment: You're trying to see if a string is even or not?? I'm having trouble seeing where you are going with this. Are you trying to see if the number of characters is even or not??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the `%` operator on a string:

```
>>> x = 'A'
>>> x % 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

When using `%` on a string, you are not getting the modulus, but are using [*`printf`-style string formatting*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting) instead. And that requires a `%`-style placeholder for the value on the right to be formatted into. With no placeholders in the string on the left, you get the error you see.

If you wanted to test if the *length* of the string is even, you need to use the `len()` function to get that length:

```
myList3 = ['even' if len(x) % 2 == 0 else 'nope' for x in myNames]
```

Demo:

```
>>> myNames = ['A','BB','CCC','DDDD']
>>> ['even' if len(x) % 2 == 0 else 'nope' for x in myNames]
['nope', 'even', 'nope', 'even']
```

Answer (score 2):

The other answers explain why your syntax is incorrect.

If you are interested, here is an alternative implementation using a dictionary.

Eliminating `if` / `else` constructs in favour of a dictionary is often both efficient and readable.

```
myNames = ['A','BB','CCC','DDDD']

mapper = {0: 'even', 1: 'nope'}
res = [mapper[len(i) %2] for i in myNames]

# ['nope', 'even', 'nope', 'even']
```

Answer (score 0):

The `%` operator, when used with a string as the left-hand argument, is for printf-style formatting. If you want to test the *length* of your strings, you need to convert from string to the length with `len`, e.g.

```
myList3 = [ 'even' if len(x) % 2==0 else 'nope' for x in myNames]
```